# Regex doesn't match url with 3 or less characters

Tags: php, regex

My regex doesn't match url with 3 or less characters.

```
$pattern = '/\w+\..{2,3}(?:\..{2,3})?(?:$|(?=\/))/i';
if (preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches) === 1) {
    echo $matches[0];
}
```

Input / Output (this works fine):
http://www.google.com // Output: google.com

But it fails on this:

```
http://www.axe.com // Output: www.axe.com
http://www.ax.com // Output: www.ax.com
http://www.a.com // Output: www.a.com
```

It takes the http:// out but has the extra `www` behind it.

So I changed it to this:

```
$pattern = '/\w+\..{2,3}(?:\..)?(?:$|(?=\/))/i';
```

Now everything works fine but:

```
http://www.google.co.uk // Output: .co.uk
```

I am matching `.co.uk` only if domain has to parts to it.

What is the best way to remove `http://` and `www` without using `parse_url()` and using regex

Comment: why don't you use `str_replace(array('http://','www.','http://www.'), '', $yoururl)`

Comment: It matches the `www` because your patters says: match one or more word characters (www), then `.`, followed by 2 or 3 of any character (axe), then `.`, followed by 2 or 3 of any character (com). If all you are trying to do is remove `http://www.` then use str_replace or `preg_replace('/https?:\/\/(www\.)?/', '', $url)`.

Comment: You could add `(?:https?://`)?` at the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since preg_replace can even take an array - you don't even need a loop, you can use:

```
$url = preg_replace('/(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(.*)\/?$/i', '$1', $url);
```

You can paste a regular expression [here](http://www.myezapp.com/apps/dev/regexp/show.ws) to see what it accomplishes.

Comment: Shortening the code doesn't help explain the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This regex will extract domains without http or https.

```
/(?<=http:\/\/www\.)([\S]+)|(?<=https:\/\/www\.)([\S]+)/gmis
```

Please see https://regex101.com/r/lW5yD6/1